# Any idea how to solve the LNK2019 - unresolved external symbol, error?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have this annoying error and have no clue on how to resolve the issue; I am using Visual Studio 2015, community version.

I am making a C/C++ console application that attaches to the GTA5.exe and modifies health using adresses.

This is the error:

```
Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ) GTAConsole
```

Here is a screenshot:
http://prntscr.com/dzbpsa.png

GTAConsole.cpp code:

```
#include "stdafx.h" // Precompiled header

#include <Windows.h> // Allows window editing; setting text, etc
#include <iostream>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std; // Allows use of std::

__int64 GetModuleBaseAddress(LPCWSTR szProcessName, LPCWSTR szModuleName)
{
    HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;

if (hSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    return 0;
}
pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
if (Process32First(hSnap, &pe32) == 0)
{
    CloseHandle(hSnap);
    return 0;
}

do
{
    if (lstrcmp(pe32.szExeFile, szProcessName) == 0)
    {
        int PID;
        PID = pe32.th32ProcessID;

        HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, PID);
        MODULEENTRY32 xModule;

        if (hSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        xModule.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32);
        if (Module32First(hSnap, &xModule) == 0)
        {
            CloseHandle(hSnap);
            return 0;
        }

        do
        {
            if (lstrcmp(xModule.szModule, szModuleName) == 0)
            {
                CloseHandle(hSnap);
                return (__int64)xModule.modBaseAddr;
            }
        } while (Module32Next(hSnap, &xModule));
        CloseHandle(hSnap);
        return 0;
    }
} while (Process32Next(hSnap, &pe32));
CloseHandle(hSnap);
return 0;
}

int Main()
{

wchar_t* WindowName = (L"Grand Theft Auto V");
wchar_t* GameTitle = (L"GTA5.exe");

HWND WindowHandle = FindWindow(NULL, WindowName);
__int64 BaseAddress = GetModuleBaseAddress(GameTitle, GameTitle);

DWORD ProcessID;
GetWindowThreadProcessId(WindowHandle, &ProcessID);

HANDLE pHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, ProcessID);

std::cout << "[sucess]: GTAV.exe has been found!" << std::endl;

for (;;)
{
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_NUMPAD1))
    {
        Sleep(250);

        float Health = 200;
        __int64 pPlayerInformationAddress = 0;

        DWORD SocialClubPlayerInformation = 0x01ED6D88;
        DWORD HealthOffset = 0x280;

        ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, (void*)(BaseAddress +      SocialClubPlayerInformation), &pPlayerInformationAddress, sizeof(pPlayerInformationAddress), NULL);
        ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, (void*)(pPlayerInformationAddress + HealthOffset), &Health, sizeof(Health), NULL);

        std::cout << Health << std::endl;
    }
}

Sleep(1);
}
```

If anyone could help, that'd be awesome!

Comment: `int Main()` should be `int main()`. `C++` is case sensitive.

Comment: Okay, I'll try it. Thank you!

Comment: I forgot main() was case sensitive, lol. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Change the line int `Main()`
by `main()`